# Making fixed elements scrollable (using javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

[PLEASE CONVERT THIS QUESTION TO A SELF-ANSWERED QUESTION]

Scrollbars appear if an element goes off the screen, so that the user can scroll to the off-screen portion of the element. [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyew6045/) illustrates my point.

However, if the element's `position` is set to `fixed`, no scrollbar appears. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbyexffa/6/). There are no scrollbars even though the `div` is going off-screen. So `fixed` content, by default, is unscrollable.

Now, this behaviour of `fixed` elements is pretty useful in a number of cases. For example, if you are making a social media website, like Facebook, you might want a three-column layout, where the left-most column (which might display the user's profile picture, his/her name, and so on) and the right-most column (which might display ads, for example) are fixed, while the middle column (which will contain all the posts) is `relative`, like this:

[image: Homepage of a social media site with a 3-column layout]

Note the vertical scrollbar appearing at the right side of this image. If the user scrolls down, only the middle column will scroll. The left-most and the right-most columns are fixed, they won't scroll (this way, your ads won't disappear when the user scrolls down).

(You can find the fiddle for this 3-column layout [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vzp2noj2/). Note: You might have to resize the output window to be able to see the right-most div)

However, the `fixed` nature of the left-most and the right-most `div`'s gives rise to a small problem of its own. Have a look at this image:

[image: Right div is going off the screen, but there's no horizontal-scrollbar]

I have resized the window. The right-most `div` is going off-screen, but there's no horizontal scroll bar, i-e, there's no way to access the off-screen portion of the right `div`. Ironically, the same behavior of `fixed` content that made it useful is now hindering user experience.

Fortunately, we can fix this problem with a bit of javascript:

```
function position(element) {
    var data = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return data.left;
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        var mainContentPosition = position(document.getElementById('MainContent'));
        if(mainContentPosition<=208) {
            var diff = 208 - mainContentPosition;
            document.getElementById('LeftContent').style = 'margin-left: -' + diff + 'px;';
            document.getElementById('RightContent').style = 'margin-left: ' + (744-diff) + 'px;';
        }
    });

    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        if(window.innerWidth>=1020) {
            document.getElementById('LeftContent').style = 'margin-left: 0px;';
            document.getElementById('RightContent').style = 'margin-left: 744px;';
        }
    });
```

Take a look at this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnn0gxnp/3/). Now, the scroll bars are working perfectly. Please also note that I've made a couple of edits to the `.css` of this fiddle as well (they are necessary for this script to do its job). I have set `overflow` to `auto` and `height` to `100%` for the `Content` div.

By the way, if you are wondering, there's no CSS-only way of making this happen (as far as I know).

Comment: you can set the max-height of the container, and set scroll: auto on it

Comment: Vertical scroll bar appears just fine (see the third image). Horizontal scroll bar doesn't.

Comment: @Saud I don't think it's possible with just pure css, because your content is fixed. `position: absolute;` may yield a different result. With fixing your content the browser isn't seeing it as something has gone off screen. If you make the window small enough you find that you do in fact get an horizontal scrollbar on the content placed in the middle that rolls over the column on the left.

Comment: Would you be completely against using something like flexbox to reach a desired 3 column layout? Or even a framework such as [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) or [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) to reach your desired 3 column layout.

Comment: Yep. Seems like CSS is not possible.
BTW, I can't use any of these frameworks on this project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a horizontal scroll-bar, correct? In this case, use overflow-x.

```
body {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a full working example of teh three column layout?

Comment: Sure. But even if you set overflow-x to auto in the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/hbyexffa/#&togetherjs=Q9DrDtbGyM) I provided, it doesn't work.

Comment: I've edited the question. Please find the link for the new fiddle at the end.

Comment: It is not possible to use only CSS to accomplish this. Scrollbar behavior is OS controlled, so while there are Javascript solutions, CSS only will not work

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 2:

> position: fixed - 
>   The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

EDIT:
Also, the only thing that I can think of right now is:

```
#Content { position: relative;}
.RightContent {position: absolute; right: 0px;}
```

Full Code:

```
body {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#LeftContent {
    position: fixed;    /*Delete this to make LeftContent scrollable*/
    overflow:hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    z-index: -1;    /*Delete this to make LeftContent scrollable*/
}
#MainContent {
    float: left;
    width: 522px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 200px; /*Delete this to make LeftContent scrollable*/
}
#RightContent {
  right: 0px;
    position: absolute; /*Delete this to make RightContent scrollable*/
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 250px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 744px; /*Delete this to make RightContent scrollable*/
    z-index: -1;    /*Delete this to make RightContent scrollable*/
}
#Content {
  position: relative;
    color: #383838;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    width: 2020px;
}
```

Comment: This would destroy the whole layout. :)